# Semantic-ui-react modal not working, typescript errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to implement Modal in my project where I use **semantic-ui-react** version **"^0.86.0"**. I have used the standard modal. But, when I use it in my project where I use typescript as well, none of the imports work. All the other components where I use semantic-ui-react work just fine. Not sure why it can't find imports for this one.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Header, Image, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

function ModalExampleModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <Modal
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
      open={open}
      trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}
    >
      <Modal.Header>Select a Photo</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Content image>
        <Image size="medium" src="/images/avatar/large/rachel.png" wrapped />
        <Modal.Description>
          <Header>Default Profile Image</Header>
          <p>
            We've found the following gravatar image associated with your e-mail
            address.
          </p>
          <p>Is it okay to use this photo?</p>
        </Modal.Description>
      </Modal.Content>
      <Modal.Actions>
        <Button color="black" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
          Nope
        </Button>
        <Button
          content="Yep, that's me"
          labelPosition="right"
          icon="checkmark"
          onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
          positive
        />
      </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default ModalExampleModal
```

I get a Typescript error for Modal:

> Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.ts

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Did u `import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";` in your index or App.js? Or you forgot to install semantic-ui-css...